# Run Vite server despite errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, vite

I'm using Vite with React and Typescript. I also made it work with ESLint and I like the `lintOnStart` ESLint's option, as it always shows all the errors together. But there is one thing that bugs me.

When there are ESLint errors on start, Vite just displays them in the console and quits. Instead, I'd like to have these errors shown in the browser and Vite running no matter what. This is how it behaves when I run the project without errors and then make some mistakes. I'm not sure why it keeps quitting on startup errors.

Can this be configured in Vite? Here's my `vite.config.ts` so far:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        eslint({
            lintOnStart: true,
        }),
        react(),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved it by doing the following:

```
...
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        eslint({
            failOnError: false,
        }),
        ...
    ],
});
```

Reference: [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-eslint#failonerror)